# trigger click an element with a specific class and attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few link elements related to a certain class and assigned row attributes to it and I'm trying to trigger click event based on the attribute value.

```html
<a class="manage_edit_nb" nb_id="1"></a> | <a class="manage_del_nb" nb_id="1"></a>
<a class="manage_edit_nb" nb_id="2"></a> | <a class="manage_del_nb" nb_id="2"></a>
<a class="manage_edit_nb" nb_id="3"></a> | <a class="manage_del_nb" nb_id="3"></a>...
```

Is it possible to trigger click or any event for a certain attribute value for a certain class?

If I try something similar to

```js
$('a[nb_id = "1"]').trigger('click');
```

it triggers click event for all elements irrespective of class but I failed to figure out how to put class reference in there!

Comment: FYI: `nb_id` is not a valid attribute

Comment: Also, `$('a.manage_edit_nb[nb_id="1"]')`

Comment: Define *assigned row attributes* Do you want to click one anchor and trigger the other one across from it? (e.g. id='1' to id='1'), btw ids must be unique, and prepending `nb_` to id just makes it invalid (i.e. does not exist, very wrong in every way)

Comment: yep nb_id is not valid! I should replace it with data-id!

Comment: Yes, that would be great, my eyes are hurting from that `nb_`  -_-

Comment: @zer00ne lol sorry about that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the `nb_id` is not a valid attribute, use `data-id` instead. `data-*` attributes are allowed, and I personally like them. And, they can be accessed using `$.attr('data-id')` method, and their value can bee updated using `$.attr('data-id', 'new value')`. Going back to the question, try using below selector

```
$('.manage_del_nb[data-id="1"]').get(0).click();
```

OR

```
$('.manage_edit_nb[data-id="1"]').get(0).click();
```

Why `.get(0)`? Assuming that the element has been bound with `.click(callback())` or `.on('click')`, the `.trigger('click')` will not do anything, so I am using `.get(0)` to get the DOM object which has that method to simulate the click event. Regardless of being said, you can use `trigger('click')` the way you're already using

Answer (score 3):

This should work fine.

```
$('a.manage_edit_nb[nb_id="1"]').trigger('click');
```

here it is working:

https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/g0txnzfw/

Comment: It sure does work nice, but the `click` event is not the same as calling `trigger`: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

Comment: @Thomas OK I've amended it :-)

Answer (score 2):

The thing that you are trying to do by the above code is triggering a click event on both '.manage_edit_nb' and '.manage_del_nb' selector and hence the event is occuring on both. Try to be little more specific by giving the class name like

```
  $('a.manage_edit_nb[nb_id = "1"]').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you need : First of all, change all `nb_id` to `data-nb_id`. and use the following code, needs jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handle click event on the class required 
    $('.manage_edit_nb').click(function(){
        // Get nb_id of that particular anchor event of the class
        var nb_id= $(this).attr('data-nb_id');
        // Switch on nb_id
        switch(nb_id){
            // Handle your cases separately here
            case "1":
            alert('Case 1');break;
            case "2":
            alert('Case 2');break;
            case "3":
            alert('Case 3');break;
        }
    });    
});
```